# Image validation works in a form but won't on other in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have something like this:

myitemrequest.php:

```
  public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'avatar_pic' => 'image',
        ];
    }
```

Which validates this:

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
                 return back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
if(request()->file("avatar_upload")) {
      $file = request()->file("avatar_upload");
     $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.jpg");
}
return back();
```

This works perfectly. Now for some reason this:

otherequest.php:

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'animage' => 'image',
        'anotherimage' => 'image',
        'anotherimage2' => 'image',
        'anotherimage3' => 'image'
    ];
}
```

which validates this:

```
  if ($backgroundImagesRequest->authorize() == false) {
        return back()
            ->withErrors($worklow_request)
            ->withInput();
    }

    if(isset($backgroundImagesRequest->animage))
    {

        $file = request()->file("animage");
        $file->storeAs('public/background_images/' . Auth::user()->id , "animage.jpg");
    }

    if(isset($backgroundImagesRequest->anotherimage1))
    {

        $file = request()->file("anotherimage1");
        $file->storeAs('public/background_images/' . Auth::user()->id , "anotherimage1.jpg");
    }

    if(isset($backgroundImagesRequest->anotherimage2))
    {

        $file = request()->file("anotherimage2");
        $file->storeAs('public/background_images/' . Auth::user()->id , "anotherimage2.jpg");
    }

    if(isset($backgroundImagesRequest->anotherimage3))
    {

        $file = request()->file("anotherimage3");
        $file->storeAs('public/background_images/' . Auth::user()->id , "anotherimage3.jpg");
    }

    return back();
}
```

Won't work, it simply sends me back with the error message "The file must be an image!". I have obviously tried with the same image as the avatar upload, which works perfectly, and it gets validated and stored accordingly. It simply won't happen with the background images.

Any ideas where could the error be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first "working" example you have for validating

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

And in second you got

```
if ($backgroundImagesRequest->authorize() == false) {
    return back()
    ->withErrors($worklow_request)
    ->withInput();
}
```

Replace that code because your validation is not the same in both examples

Comment: Actually both were correctly working. I just forgot to add  enctype="multipart/form-data" to the <form>.